# Accessing arguments/parameters of an Allure report during execution?

Tags: node.js, automated-tests, allure, wdio-v6, wdio

In the testing framework we are using allures .addArgument method to add a parameter to the report for the name of team which owns a particular test.

```
AllureReporter.addArgument('teamName', 'myTeam');.
```

Many tests have already been written, some with this argument missing and I want to know how I can access the argument values which have been set on an active allure report object while the test is running (maybe in the afterTest hook) so I can automatically add a default team if argument is missing.

Another use case would be to check if any allure steps are open at the end of a passing test and end them if so.

Report looks like
[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to the [implementation of `addArgument`](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-js-commons/blob/b8cc258823eb9e2252652598bff83942879b4d27/runtime.js#L56), this should work:

```js
const currentTest = allure.getCurrentTest();
const param = currentTest.parameters.filter(p => p.kind === 'argument' && p.name === 'teamName');
if (!param) {
  currentTest.addParameter('argument', 'teamName', 'myTeam');
}
```

(untested)

Comment: I appreciate your answer, it appears that the version of allure which WDIO testing framework has implemented does not operate in this same manner and getCurrentTest is inaccessible for me

Comment: Try: `const currentTest = allureReporter['_allure'].getCurrentTest();`